# Securing PHP remember me using a client side cookie

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I know this question may be asked many times but most of them suggests you to store ip+username+password and hash this whole thing and compare, instead I came up with a different solution for my website, I want to do something like this:

Am using session to store username, userid, timezone offset etc, now suppose we say a user logs in and he checked **remember me**, I'll set sessions and then I'll generate an variable uniqueid holding random 12-13 digit ID, after setting this I'll create a cookie using this unique ID and username on his browser and also store it in my database and when he comes back I'll check whether that id and username cookie is set if yes than select username, remembermeid from database where username=cookie username and than set sessions again and throw him on the homepage else redirect to login page..

If he logs out I'll delete all cookies and will update the unique value back after he selects remember and logs in...

Any problem in doing this? or a better way to do it? I don't want password to be saved in cookie, even in a hashed state..or what am doing is perfect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as I understand your description, when a user logs in (and wishes to remain permanently logged in), you do the following:

- Create a random token.
- Save the random token in the user database record for that user (or in a separate table containing the username and the token).
- Set cookies on the user's browser containing the username and the token.

When the user returns and does not have an active session, but does have the cookies set above, you look up their username in the database.  If the database contains a "remember me" token for that user, and the token matches the one in the cookie, you create a new session for the user.

When the user logs out, you delete the cookies from their browser and also delete the token from the database.

---

If so, that's a perfectly safe design, *as long as* the token is long enough and generated by a secure random number generator (like `/dev/urandom` on Unix).  You say your tokens are "12-13 digits long", which translates to a little over 40 bits; that's a bit on the low side, I'd recommend at least twice that.  Also, you don't say *how* you're generating the tokens; just using PHP's `rand` or `mt_rand` isn't safe, as their output may be predictable.

I would also suggest two improvements: First, hash the token before storing it in the database (any cryptographic hash function will do, e.g. SHA-1 — with long random tokens you don't need any special password-hashing function like PBKDF2) so that an attacker who manages to copy the database won't get all the tokens.  Second, include an expiration date for the tokens in the database, so that a single compromised token won't remain valid forever.

Comment: Answer what I was looking for, perfect, it is simple explanation, btw I am using mt_rand and rand for generating 10 digit random user id, so I can use mt_rand and than hash that value using sha1 and store this value in my database, and also on the cookie...thanks ;)

Comment: Hashing the output of `mt_rand` doesn't make it any less predictable: if you can predict the input to the hash, you can predict the output. (It _might_ make it somewhat harder for an attacker to infer the state just by observing the output, but that depends a lot on just how the hashing is done.) You should use e.g. [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks but am not going to secure it so much unless and until I make my website popular, till than jsut crypting mt_rand will work for now ;) thank you again, was a simple explanation, and I awarded +1 for mentioning to hash tokens, so now after hashing tokens, length of the string will be 40 digits long(default of SHA1)

Comment: To me, that sounds a lot like "I won't plug that leak in my boat until I have more passengers on board." It's not _that_ much harder to do it right from the start, compared with the work you had to do to kluge it with `mt_rand` anyway. But, hey, whatever floats your boat (or not)... :)

Comment: haha that was cool, I am building a biggy boat, you'll get a ticket for soon... ;) so more or less my way was correct, it's just I need to crpyt ...

Answer (score 1):

You never have to store username and/or password in cookies. All you need to store is one unique identificator (randomly generated) which can be compared with hashed session identificator in database.

Comment: ya that's what I meant, say a unique ID/hashed 40 digit string I'll store in my database as a rememberme_id field and while he come's back I'll compare right? and btw say if, am saying IF it happens that 2 users share a common hashed ID, than what? is it better to save username in a different cookie so that I can compare if username=username and rememberme_id=hashed id than pass else fail

Comment: You need to look for valid session ID on each request anyway. Option "Remember me" should only add flag to session to define longer expiration time;

Comment: sorry but am not getting here what to flag? suppose if I get session id using session_id than what next? can you explain me by editing your answer?

Comment: Don't use PHP built-in session for this. You need to use your own session system (cookie + database) so you can have full control over expiration times.

Comment: inshort I'll make a sessionid cookie and store that id in my database and when he comes back I'll check whether that cookie is there then I'll compare it with the database if yes than again set session variables and will redirect him to his home page else login page right?